# Atribuir valor à uma variável em uma controller e não modificar o valor da variável $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Gostaria de saber por que quando atribuo o valor à uma variável dentro de uma controller vindo de uma variável $scope e altero o valor dessa variável, é alterado também o valor da variável $scope. Por exemplo:

```
$scope.viagem.valorFrete = 1.500,20; 
var viagemPersistencia.valorFrete = $scope.viagem.valorFrete.replace('.','').replace(',','.');
```

Depois `var viagemPersistencia.valorFrete= 1500.20` e o valor de `$scope.viagem.valorFrete` igual ou seja **1500.20** quando poderia ser **1.500,20** na view, gostaria que o valor de `$scope.viagem.valorFrete` não se alterasse.

**Editado**
 À pedido segue parte do meu código para não se estender.

Parte do html:

```
<input id="freteviagem" maxlength="9" type="text" name="freteviagem" ng-model="viagem.valorFrete">
      <div id="btn-salvar" style="text-align:right;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="salvar(viagem)">
          <span class="fonte-viagem">Salvar</span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.salvar = function(viagem) {
     var viagemPersistencia = viagem;
     viagemPersistencia.valorFrete = viagemPersistencia.valorFrete === 
     undefined || viagemPersistencia.valorFrete === null ? null 
     (viagemPersistencia.valorFrete + "")
     .replace('.','').replace(',','.');
    //VALOR $scope.viagem.valorFrete é o mesmo de viagemPersistencia.valorFrete neste momento 
  }
```

Comment: Seria interessante você exemplificar com código, para que eu possa te responder com precisão.

Comment: Você precisa clonar o objeto ao invés de atribuir.

Comment: Var x = angular.copy(y)… se não me engano é assim.

Comment: [edson alves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64053/edson-alves) deu certo conforme você comentou segue [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/bvt7xcd0/) , mas por que isso ocorre? e pelo jeito só com objetos.

Answer (score 1):

No Javascript as variáveis são passadas por **referência**, então se a variável `viagemPersistencia` sofrer alguma alteração, a cópia guardada de `viagem` também vai ser impactada.

Fazendo uma **cópia sem referencia** (`angular.copy`), se cria um objeto novo sem vínculo com o original. Então a ideia seria garantir que o conteúdo de `viagem` não vai ter alterações após alterar `viagemPersistencia`.

Tente usar [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
var viagemPersistencia = angular.copy(viagem);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: [Lucas Duarte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82005/lucas-duarte) - Havia me esquecido do detalhe de variáveis do tipo objeto passadas como referência, no caso é porque a variável é do tipo objeto, porque se fosse do tipo primitivo não aconteceria o mesmo. Valeu